# Dynamically changing a form contents via jQuery in rails 3 and submit it via javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

My view code:

```
 <%= form_for(item, :url => update_cart_path) do |item_form| %>
    <tr>
        <td width="300"><%=item.variant.product.name%> <%= "(" + variant_options(item.variant) + ")" unless item.variant .option_values.empty? %></td>
        <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency item.price %></td>
        <td class="qty"><%=item.quantity%></td>
        <td class="total"><span><%= number_to_currency (item.price * item.quantity)%></span></td>
        <td class="edit"><%= link_to(image_tag('/images/admin/icons/edit.png'), '#', :class => 'edit') %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

My "inspect element" output in google chrome code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cart" class="edit_line_item" id="edit_line_item_1070870267" method="post"></form>
<tr> 
    <td width="300">Ruby on Rails Tote </td> 
    <td class="price">$15.99</td> 
    <td class="qty">2</td> 
    <td class="total"><span>$31.98</span></td> 
    <td class="edit"><a href="#" class="edit"><img alt="Edit" src="/images/admin/icons/edit.png?1299481899" /></a> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

My source page code of the site:

```
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cart" class="edit_line_item" id="edit_line_item_1070870267" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="p31zTaCWOkCTDPyMMzAlfvmSvrcyCSVEG4Lj59xne6Q=" /></div> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="300">Ruby on Rails Tote </td> 
        <td class="price">$15.99</td> 
        <td class="qty">2</td> 
        <td class="total"><span>$31.98</span></td> 
        <td class="edit"><a href="#" class="edit"><img alt="Edit" src="/images/admin/icons/edit.png?1299481899" /></a> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    </form>
```

my javascript code:

```
(function($){
    // Remove an item from the cart by setting its quantity to zero and posting the update form
    init = function(){
        $('tbody#line-items a.edit').show().click(function(){
            var edit, qty;

            edit = $(this).parents('tr').children('.edit').html();
            qty = $(this).parents('tr').children('.qty').html();


            $('tbody#line-items a.edit').hide();

            quantity = $(this).parents('tr').children('.qty').html();
            //<a href="#" class="edit" data-method="submit" rel="nofollow">

            $(this).parents('tr').children('.qty').replaceWith('<td class="qty"><input class="line_item_quantity" id="order_line_items_attributes_0_quantity" name="order[line_items_attributes][0][quantity]" size="3" type="text" value="'+quantity+'" /></td>');
            $(this).parents('tr').children('.edit').replaceWith('<td class="edit"><a href="#" class="update" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Update" src="/images/admin/icons/tick.png" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete"><img alt="Delete" src="/images/admin/icons/delete.png" /></a></td>')

            $('a.update').click(function(){
                $('form.edit_line_item').submit();
                return false;
            });

            $('tbody#line-items a.delete').click(function(){
                $('tbody#line-items a.edit').show();

                $(this).parents('tr').children('.edit').replaceWith('<td class=edit>'+edit+'</td>');
                $("input.line_item_quantity").parent().replaceWith('<td class=qty>'+qty+'</td>');

                init();

                return false;
            }); 
            return false;
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        init();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My javascript code basically replaces the edit button to an update and cancel button if it was clicked. My question is why my params don't contain the inputs (that were dynamically created via javascript) in my form once it get submitted?
Is the dynamic changes messing up the form that is going to be submitted?
What I wanted to do was to click on an edit button, some javascript code will create an input textfield and a submit button. I then can click submit sending the information to a controller but I can't get hold of the submitted info. Any help will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a HTML validation problem in form creation, the form tag should be inside div, span, td, li, i.e all granular html tag which can hold data. Here its rendering between table and row, which is wrong. so you should write form_for before creating htm table  as

```
 <%= form_for(item, :url => update_cart_path) do |item_form| %>
<table>

   <tr>
        <td width="300"><%=item.variant.product.name%> <%= "(" + variant_options(item.variant) + ")" unless item.variant .option_values.empty? %></td>
        <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency item.price %></td>
        <td class="qty"><%=item.quantity%></td>
        <td class="total"><span><%= number_to_currency (item.price * item.quantity)%></span></td>
        <td class="edit"><%= link_to(image_tag('/images/admin/icons/edit.png'), '#', :class => 'edit') %>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<%end %>
```

Comment: this table might contain several items, so you are suggesting that I use one form for all the items and not one form for each item?

Comment: ideally, created HTML should be valid. The <table> tag can have <tr> or <tbody> as child element. Here your form tag is rendering between <table> and <tr>. You can create form tag outside of table which can have form filde or can create complete form including inputs inside of <td>.

Comment: I changed the whole form. I used div tags instead of the table tags.